# How to add Bootstrap bg-x (e.g., bg-danger) classes to input textboxes?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The background color associated with Bootstrap's `bg-danger` class is not being applied to an input textbox of class `form-control`. How can this be done?

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="form-group has-error">
        <input type="text" class="form-control bg-danger">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add style to your input as  .form-control{background-color: #f2dede;} to get desired result as form-control override the bg-info class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style definitions for the `form-control` class come below the style definitions for the `bg-danger` class in bootstrap.css (or bootstrap.min.css). Because of that, form-control styles override the background-color with white.

You would need to create your own custom class/styles somewhere to override form-control with a different background color.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as the other answers said, `form-control` comes after `bg-danger`, and so its `background-color` will override the background of `bg-danger`.

But I was able to use both classes without needing an additional class. Suppose I have the following HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control bg-danger" />
```

So I just needed do add in my css the following code

```
.form-control.bg-danger {
    background-color: #f2dede; 
}
```

So, when an element has *both* the classes `form-control` and `bg-danger`, he will get this `background-color` (the same of `bg-danger`, but if you want you can choose another color). Obviously I can do the same with all the other `bg-x` bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

Form-control and bg-danger won't work together. Mention a different class in input field and set it's styling properties. You can use it for one input field or for all the fields.

```css
.background-input{
  background-color:#ff1a1a;  
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
        <div class="form-group has-error">
            <input type="text" class="form-control background-input">
        </div>
    </div>
```